# A Script works with IDLE(Geany) but not when opened directly by double click

Tags: python

Sorry, I just don't know how to ask this question with proper computer language?
This is my piece of code. When I try to run it from windows by double-clicking the `.py` file, it jumps out after entering the user input **in the middle of the program!** But it works properly by the IDLE(Geany)! Does anyone know why? because there is no error inside the program!

``
print('Hi!prime number checker!')
user_num = input('Please, enter a number:\n' )
user_num = int(user_num)
if user_num == 1:
print('prime')
if user_num == 2:
print('prime')
if user_num > 2:
for num in range (2, user_num):
x = user_num % num
if x == 0 :
print('not prime')
exit()
else:
print ('prime')
exit()

```
I don't want to add an input line at the end of the program because it is not the real problem.
I am wondering why this is happening? Why does this jump out after entering the user input, but it runs properly with Geany?
```

Comment: An `input()` at the end is exactly what you need to make this script usable when double-clicked.  Without it, the window will disappear before you have any chance to see the results.  An IDE doesn't close just because the script finished, so doesn't need that.

Comment: Thanks, but why it jumps out before printing the result? there is no exit command? also, the program will only be terminated when someone enters something not by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use `break`.

Snippet modified:

```
print('Hi!prime number checker!')
user_num = input('Please, enter a number:\n' )
user_num = int(user_num)
if user_num == 1:
    print('prime')
if user_num == 2:
    print('prime')
if user_num > 2:
    for num in range (2, user_num):
        x = user_num % num
        if x == 0 :
            print('not prime')
            break
            
        else:
            print ('prime')
            break
```